# URLConnection FileNotFoundException on HTTP port 80

Tags: java, jsp, resin

I have a JSP file named `aniltest.jsp` which has following code:

```
<%
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL("http://localhost:80/admin/anil1.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(aURL.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("content of anil1.txt: " + inputLine);

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading content of url");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
%>
```

In the above code I am trying to read a text file named `anil1.txt` which is located at http://localhost:80/admin/anil1.txt

I get below error when I run: http://localhost:80/aniltest.jsp

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:80/admin/anil1.txt
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
  at _jsp._aniltest__jsp._jspService(_aniltest__jsp.java:93)
  at _jsp._aniltest__jsp._jspService(_aniltest__jsp.java:31)
  at com.caucho.jsp.JavaPage.service(JavaPage.java:64)
  at com.caucho.jsp.Page.pageservice(Page.java:548)
  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.PageFilterChain.doFilter(PageFilterChain.java:194)
  at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
  at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
  at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1349)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1305)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1289)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1197)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:993)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
  at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
  at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
  at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
```

Though I can access the file `http://localhost:80/admin/anil1.txt` in the web browser without any problem: I am using latest Resin server. I am totally stuck and can't figure it out what is the problem.

Comment: Is port 80 not a reserved port?

Comment: I don't think so because I can access the file from the browser without any problem.

Comment: Try to get a URLConnection object first by aURL.openConnection(), then call urlConnection.connect(), and then urlConnection.getInputStream()

Comment: I tired that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
URLConnection  uCon = aUrl.openConnection();
InputStream is = uCon.getInputStream();
```

then read bytes from the inputstream

Comment: Try creating a file in the http://localhost:80/admin/ directory and see if it can do that

Comment: try creating at run time.

Comment: created a new text file while server is running. But still same problem I can open in browser but can't with jsp

Answer (score 0):

The code does not seem to have any problem. You can check if localhost resolves to anywhere else, you can try 127.0.0.1 instead. Mentioning port is not mandatory, it should work otherwise too (80 is default).

Try sniffing the request and response with wireshark if the problem continues.

Is the url protected by any authentication? Try clearing browser cookie and cache and initiate a fresh request.

Comment: No URL is not protected by any authentication. When I try 127.0.0.1 it doesn't work. Tried clearing browser and fresh request still not working.

Comment: Can you try writing the same code on a Java class instead of JSP and try if it works? What you're experiencing is unusual and hence we are trying weird ways.

Comment: It works well from a Java class code instead of JSP. What is the problem why it does't work with JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys File not found exception was because of Skype which was using port 80 for incoming connections. After chaning the port it works well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's interesting.

From my previous comment - 
What you're experiencing is unusual and hence we are trying weird ways.

Am curious about how it worked when you tried from browser. Can you try from browser keeping the Skype running?

Comment: When my Skype is running I can't access it as I said because Skype was using port 80. When I change the port of Skype it works well.